# Why am I getting "permission denied" error message when running Linux find command

Tags: linux, find

I am executing the following command:

```
find / -name ben
```

I've been wondering, why is there so many permission denied when running the above command? Even those directories that doesn't contain the name `ben` show up.

Comment: Because your `find` starts in the root directory of your system (`/`) and if you're not the root user you don't have permission to look into the most system relevant directories like `/proc` and so on. On the other hand, as root user you'll have the same message for user's home directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to search for a file, you need to be able to read all directories.

If a directory that is searched does not grant you read and "execute" permissions, you get a permission denied error from the find program.

If the read permission for you is missing, then you cannot see what files are in such a directory.

If the "execute" (search) permission is missing for you, then you cannot `chdir` into that diectory and as a result, you cannot ceck sub-directories in that directory.

Every operating system needs (for security reasons) directories that cannot be searched by ordinary people and other users may have closed their home directory as well.